# How to draw line on over all element html

Tags: html, css, svg, line, draw

I want to draw a line connect two div and I used a svg with position absolute but the button between two div is can't be click.

How could I draw a line with z-index max, position absolute and it can click on element under this line.
If you have any idea it will help me a lot, thank you!
[this is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNxre.png)

My code :

````
<html>
<body>
<div style="border: solid; width: 150px;height: 150px;"> div1 </div>
<svg height="210" width="500" style="position: absolute;">
  <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
<div style="border: #3F3F3F;width: 150px;height: 150px;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: flex-end;">
 <button>button </button>
</div>
<div style="border: solid;width: 150px;height: 150px;top: 360px;position: absolute;left: 169px;"> div3 </div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add `pointer-events:none` to the svg element.
2. It may be better to use a transformed div with height:1px instead of an svg:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.rect {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  border: solid 1px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#rect2 {
  left:350px;
  top: 400px;
}

.line {
  width: 400px;
  height:1px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  transform:rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin:0 0;
  top:200px;
  left:100px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top:280px;
  left: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <div class="rect" id="rect1"></div>
  <div class="rect" id="rect2"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the `SVG` element `z-index:-1` and the button will be click

Just add the following code to your CSS

```
svg{
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add button's style -> position:fixed